# Strange ClassCastException with a Spinner

Tags: android, spinner, classcastexception

I have this code:

```
Spinner entrega=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.comboentrega); //This is the line where it cracks
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.arrayentrega, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    // Apply the adapter to the spinner
    entrega.setAdapter(adapter);
```

In the layout:

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/comboentrega"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView4" />
```

When I run the app, I receive this stacktrace:

```
03-13 11:43:13.748: E/AndroidRuntime(1668): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-13 11:43:13.748: E/AndroidRuntime(1668): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.publidirecta.AppAzafata/com.publidirecta.AppAzafata.Incidencias}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.Button
03-13 11:43:13.748: E/AndroidRuntime(1668):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1659)
03-13 11:43:13.748: E/AndroidRuntime(1668):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1675)
03-13 11:43:13.748: E/AndroidRuntime(1668):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:121)
03-13 11:43:13.748: E/AndroidRuntime(1668):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:943)
03-13 11:43:13.748: E/AndroidRuntime(1668):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-13 11:43:13.748: E/AndroidRuntime(1668):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
03-13 11:43:13.748: E/AndroidRuntime(1668):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3701)
03-13 11:43:13.748: E/AndroidRuntime(1668):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-13 11:43:13.748: E/AndroidRuntime(1668):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-13 11:43:13.748: E/AndroidRuntime(1668):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
03-13 11:43:13.748: E/AndroidRuntime(1668):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:624)
03-13 11:43:13.748: E/AndroidRuntime(1668):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-13 11:43:13.748: E/AndroidRuntime(1668): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.Button
03-13 11:43:13.748: E/AndroidRuntime(1668):     at com.publidirecta.AppAzafata.Incidencias.onCreate(Incidencias.java:122)
03-13 11:43:13.748: E/AndroidRuntime(1668):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
03-13 11:43:13.748: E/AndroidRuntime(1668):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1623)
```

Why am I getting that ClassCastException android.widget.Button, if I am not casting to Button? In case it may help, the Spinner was first attached to the right side of the screen,  and was working just fine. I noticed it and attached it to the left side, where it must be, and the exception started.

Anybody has any idea about this? Thank you.

Comment: Try cleaning your project and running again. It may be the R has become corrupted.

Comment: What is line number 122 of Incidencias.java?

Comment: TheReader, it's commented in the code.

Comment: Joseph, cleaned the project and its ok now. Write it in an answer if you want your upvote :) Thank you man.

Comment: As @JosephEarl said, sometimes Eclipse needs a nice clean, as it happens once with me where an error occurred on a commented line !